# How can I make my application appear as an option to import photos from sdcard / camera

Tags: ios, macos

I am writing a photo application for MacOS/iOS. I want my application to be able to import raw images from cameras and sd cards. 
When an sd card is mounted (inserted) macOS offers a choice of applications to import the photos to e.g. Adobe Lightroom, Apple Photos, etc. 
What do I need to do so my application will appear as one of the import options?

Answer (score 0):

File associations are handled by the Launch Services technology. 
For information about Launch Services, you will need to study https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/launch_services